# Magento2 Pulling in Customer Data from Third Party instead of Data

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.2, magento2-enterprise

We have a Magento 2 EE 2.1 App:

However, we do not store the Customer entity data in Magento. We query a third party service (over Rest API) to pull the customer information when required.

Each time a user is created we create a dummy user in Magento and store his actual details in the third party service with we keeping an only id of the record present in the third party service.

Now, in magento I need a way where in every time I need Customer info, I would pull that in from the third party service instead of Magento Customer EAV.

I believe (I may be wrong here) Magento 2 design (Service Contracts) is such that the data need not be pulled in always from Database but it is possible to call a REST service to fetch it.

Question is how do I achieve this in code ?

Comment: U need obviously copy of that in Magento & Sync things using Observer & REST API to third Party